# Auth0 Angular2 invalid_token

Tags: angular, oauth, auth0

I followed tutorial for Auth0 and Angular 2 and got an error:
`invalid_token` `Algorithm HS256 is not supported. (Expected algs: [RS256])`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set your `Client Type` at https://manage.auth0.com/#/clients to `Single Page Application`

[image]

[Solution originally found here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angular-samples/issues/30)